# Cannot get textfield values from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, textfield

I have made 2 php pages. One page is "doc.php" and other is "chkval.php". I have used some javascript code to generate textfields in "doc.php". And by using $POST , I am trying to catch textfield values in "chkval.php" page, but the textfield values are not being catched with the error

> Use of undefined constant regCardRecp - assumed 'regCardRecp' in
>   D:\wamp\www\chkval.php on line 3 regCardRecp

Below is my Complete code.

**doc.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Record Entry</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById("select");
            var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
            select.onchange = function()
            {
                var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                texts.innerHTML = "";


                if(val==9 ){

                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Reg Card Reception Date (SSC): <input type="text" name="regCardRecp" id="regCardRecp"></div>'
                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Reg Card Issue Date (SSC):<input type="text" name="regCardIss" id="regCardIss">'

                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Roll no Slip Reception Date (SSC):<input type="text" name="rollSlipRecp" id="rollSlipRecp"></div>'
                 texts.innerHTML += '<div>Roll no Slip Issue Date (SSC):<input type="text" name="rollSlipIss" id="rollSlipIss"></div>'    

                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Reception Date (SSC-I):<input type="text" name="marksheetRecpI" id="marksheetRecpI"/></div>'
                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Issue Date (SSC-I):<input type="text" name="marksheetIssI" id="marksheetIssI"/></div>'

                texts.innerHTML += '<div>Result (SSC-I):<input type="radio" name="Sresult" value="pass" /> Pass<input type="radio" name="Sresult" value="fail" /> Fail</div>'




                }
                if(val==10 ){
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Reception Date (SSC-II):<input type="text" name="marksheetRecpII" id="marksheetRecpII"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Issue Date (SSC-II):<input type="text" name="marksheetIssII" id="marksheetIssII"></div>'


                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Certificate Reception Date (SSC):<input type="text" name="certRecp" id="certRecp"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Certificate Issue Date (SSC):<input type="text" name="certIss" id="certIss"></div>'

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Result (SSC-II):<input type="radio" name="Sresult1" value="pass" /> Pass<input type="radio" name="Sresult1" value="fail" /> Fail</div>'

                      //  texts.innerHTML += '<div></div>'

                      };

                if( val==11){

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Reg Card Reception Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HhregCardRecp" id="HregCardRecp"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Reg Card Issue Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HregCardIss" id="HregCardIss">'

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Roll no Slip Reception Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HrollSlipRecp" id="HrollSlipRecp"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Roll no Slip Issue Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HrollSlipIss" id="HrollSlipIss"></div>'


                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Reception Date (HSSC-I):<input type="text" name="HmarksheetRecpI" id="HmarksheetRecpI"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Issue Date (HSSC-I):<input type="text" name="HmarksheetIssI" id="HmarksheetIssI"></div>'

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Result (HSSC-I):<input type="radio" name="Hresult" value="pass" /> Pass<input type="radio" name="Hresult" value="fail" /> Fail</div>'





                };

                if(val==12 ){

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Reception Date (HSSC-II):<input type="text" name="HmarksheetRecpII" id="HmarksheetRecpII"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Marks Sheet Issue Date (HSSC-II):<input type="text" name="HmarksheetIssII" id="HmarksheetIssII"></div>'


                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Certificate Reception Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HcertRecp" id="HcertRecp"></div>'
                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Certificate Issue Date (HSSC):<input type="text" name="HcertIss" id="HcertIss"></div>'

                      texts.innerHTML += '<div>Result (HSSC-II):<input type="radio" name="Hresult1" value="pass" /> Pass<input type="radio" name="Hresult1" value="fail" /> Fail</div>'


                };






            }
        }

    </script>


</head>
<body>


<form id="myform" method="post" action="chkval.php" onSubmit="chkval.php">

<h1 align="center">Documents Record Entry</h1>
<table width=50% align = 'center'>

<tr><td>Session:</td><td>
<select name="session">
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>

<select name="session">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>

-

<select name="session">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
</select>
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>
Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</td>

<td>
Board:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="board" id="board">
</td>
</tr>


<tr><td>Class:</td><td>
<select id="select" size="1" name="class" >
<option value="1" >1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">Matric-I</option> 
<option value="10">Matric-II</option>
<option value="11" >HSSC-I</option>
<option value="12">HSSC-II</option>
<option value="13">Bachelor</option>


</select>
<hr/>

        <div id="texts"></div></td></tr>


<td>

</td>



<br>
</td>
<tr><td>Remarks:<textarea name="remarks" cols="24" rows="3"></textarea></td></tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**chkval.php**

```
<?php
$regCardRecp = $_POST['regCardRecp'];
echo(regCardRecp);

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: In some places you have not closed the input tag , correct the unclosed tags.You have not closed the input tag with name as 'regCardRecp' , that could be the reason for error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is here you are just mising a **$** symbol on your  **echo (regCardRecp);**

```
<?php

    $regCardRecp = $_POST['regCardRecp'];
    echo($regCardRecp);

?>
```